# How to get list of all pages

Tags: kentico

How can I get a list of all pages (url) in a Kentico site?

I like to check whether the page name contains space (%20) before I replace it with '-'.

Thanks.

Comment: Kentico version 7. Need to make a case for the stakeholder to have a url list of all pages, before any changes are made. Is there a way in CMSDesk or Sitemanager to get this, without programming?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the latest published version of pages use

```
TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
var pages = tree.SelectNodes();
```

See https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Working+with+pages+in+the+API for more details.

Comment: Need to make a case for the stakeholder to have a url list of all pages, before any changes are made. Is there a way in CMSDesk or Sitemanager (Version 7) to get this, without programming?

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to take that step. The default config in Kentico is to replace the space character, along with several others. You can set what the replacement character will be and add your own characters to replace via Settings-->URLs and SEO. There's [more info](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/URL+format+and+configuration) in the Kentico documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to make a case for the stakeholder to have a url list of all pages, before any changes are made. Is there a way in CMSDesk or Sitemanager (Version 7) to get this, without programming?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do so with the GoogleSiteMap webpart. After you set your parameters, use a transformation along these lines-- `<%# GetAbsoluteUrl(GetDocumentUrlForFeed(), Eval("SiteName")) %><br />` (Sorry I didn't reply sooner; I hadn't seen your note till now.)

Answer (score 0):

In **Pages** application, you can select the document root and choose list view. Button in left above document tree. Check "Show all levels" option after that. You can choose the number of item per page and export it to XML or Excel file (choose appropriate menu in command column).

Unfortunately, you will have document name and not document URL.